# Como faço para criar uma caso de teste neste cenário

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, testes-de-unidade, moq

Esta é a classe que preciso fazer a implementação dos casos de testes:

```
    public class JWTService : IJWTService
    {
        private RequestExtension _requestExtension;
        

        public JWTService(RequestExtension requestExtension)
        {
            _requestExtension = requestExtension;
            
        }

        public async Task<TokenResponseDomain> GerarTokenAsync(string urlContato, UsuarioDomain usuario)
        {
            var tokenResponse = new TokenResponseDomain();
            UsuarioDomain usuarioExistente;
            try
            {
                string url = $"{urlContato}?id_email_contato={usuario.Email}";
                var usuarioRetorno = await _requestExtension.GetAsync(url);
                usuarioExistente = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsuarioDomain>($"{usuarioRetorno.Response}");

                if (usuarioExistente == null)
                {
                    tokenResponse.Token = null;
                    tokenResponse.Mensagem = "Usuário inválido!";
                    return tokenResponse;
                }

                var senhaVerificada = this.CompararSenha(usuarioExistente.Senha, usuario.Senha);

                if (!senhaVerificada)
                {
                    tokenResponse.Token = null;
                    tokenResponse.Mensagem = "Senha inválida!";
                    return tokenResponse;
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tokenResponse.Token = null;
                tokenResponse.Mensagem = "Erro ao tentar obter usuário!";                
                return tokenResponse;
            }

            tokenResponse = this.CreateToken(usuarioExistente);

            return tokenResponse;
        }
    }
```

E aqui esta o caso de teste que estou tentando implementar:

```
    public class CriarJWTTest
    {
        private readonly Faker _faker;
        private readonly AutoMocker _mocker;
        private readonly UsuarioService _usuarioService;
        private readonly Mock<RequestExtension> _requestExtensionMock;
        private readonly Mock<SecretEnvironmentSettings> _secretEnvironmentSettings;
        private readonly Mock<OAuthIntegration> _oAuthIntegration;


        private readonly InvestidorContatosController _controller;
        private readonly JWTService _jwtService;

        public CriarJWTTest()
        {
            _mocker = new AutoMocker();
            _faker = new Faker();

            _secretEnvironmentSettings = new Mock<SecretEnvironmentSettings>(MockBehavior.Strict, _faker.Random.AlphaNumeric(5), _faker.Random.AlphaNumeric(5), _faker.Random.AlphaNumeric(5));
            _oAuthIntegration = new Mock<OAuthIntegration>(_secretEnvironmentSettings.Object);
            _requestExtensionMock = new Mock<RequestExtension>(MockBehavior.Strict,_oAuthIntegration.Object);

            _jwtService = new JWTService(_requestExtensionMock.Object);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task CriarJWTValidoTest()
        {
            var usuario = new UsuarioDomain()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Nome = _faker.Person.FullName,
                Email = _faker.Person.Email,
            };

            var response = new ResponseDomain(200, true, new
            {
                Id = 12,
                Nome = usuario.Nome,
                Email = usuario.Email,
                Senha = _faker.Internet.Password()
            }, "");
            var urlContato = _faker.Internet.Url();

            _requestExtensionMock.Setup(x => x.GetAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(response);


            var result = await _jwtService.GerarTokenAsync(urlContato, usuario);

            //Assert
        }
    }
```

Estou tomando um exception nestes instrução do Moq - `_requestExtensionMock.Setup(x => x.GetAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(response);` - exception: System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.GetAsync(It.IsAny())
Non-overridable members (here: RequestExtension.GetAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions

Preciso mockar o retorno desta parte: `var usuarioRetorno = await _requestExtension.GetAsync(url);`

Não posso mexer na implementação da classe, pois se trada de um sistema que esta prestes a entrar em produção e esta como débito técnico a implementação dos casos de teste para ela